# How to generate XML documentation files in CUDA C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, xml-documentation

I know that I can generate XML documentation files in **C++** by choosing this option under C\C++.
[image]

The problem now that I can't do the same thing for **CUDA C++**.
[image]
Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no direct solution for this, but I did it by creating a dummy project with the same name and same function names with same comments in **C++**, I didn't have to write the contents of the functions, then built it to generate the required XML documentation file.